# Unity3D Assets Bundle Manifest

Tags: unity-game-engine, manifest, assetbundle

Good Day!
I'm new with assets bundle in unity, so I have a question:
"Is it necessary to use **AssetBundleManifest** with *LoadFromCacheOrDownload* function"? And, is **AssetBundleManifest** file common for all bundles?

In my project, I create a lot of new asset bundles every month. So should I rewrite AssetBundleManifest manually every time?

P.S. I apologize if the wording of the question is incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Pls show what you have tried before you ask, try a read on [FAQ] first.

Answer (score 0):

AssetBundleManifest is not mandatory it is just a suggestion from Unity so you know what's packed into the asset bundle.

You can have a bundle without a manifest but if you decide to use it you'll probably need to use it every time you build a new bundle.